# implement form authentication on some pages not all pages

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to implement form authentication on some pages not all pages.

In my application many other pages are there which I want make as public like contact us, about us and all.

For some pages I want to implement form authentication.

Please help me on this.

```
<authorization>
  <deny users ="?" />
  <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had a directory called "Administration" which contained all the administration pages, you could add the following to your web.config:

```
<location path="Administration">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Then only users in the role "Admin" can access the pages in the "Administration" directory. The path can also be substituted for a specific page rather than a directory if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different directories for different pages. For example those pages that you want to make public to every one can be in one folder and put a web.config file on that folder allowing to all users.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like that

```
<configuration>
       <location path="test.aspx">
        <system.web>
         <authorization>
          <allow users="?"/>
          <deny users="*" />
         <authorization>
        </system.web>
      </location>  
   </configuration>
```

[Check For More knowledge](http://forums.asp.net/t/1199910.aspx/1)

Hope it works for you.